# Apache Django URL problem

Tags: django, apache, url

I allow users to submit a query at mysite.com/go/QUERY\

If the query contains "/" Apache chokes.

From urls.py:

```
(r'^go/(?P<querytext>.*)$', 'mysite.engine.views.go'),
```

Try:

```
http://mysite.com/go/http%3A%2F%2F
```

Result:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /go/http:// was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu) Server at ...
```

BUT, if I enter the non URL quoted values it works:
`http://mysite.com/go/http://` WORKS just fine...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your httpd is blocking encoded slashes.

try adding `AllowEncodedSlashes On` to your apache config to [enable encoded slashes in apache (docs)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes)

Comment: Nice one! I didn't even think to look at Apache as the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, I ran into this same problem. I suspected Apache was the cause, but I didn't realize there was an explicit setting for this.

Answer (score 2):

From the Django docs it looks like you're only supposed to use the `(?P....)` notation when implementing a named group (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/http/urls/#named-groups).

Try fixing your regex by either getting rid of the `?P` or completing the syntax and naming the group like `(?P<search-term>.*)`

Comment: sorry, the HTML took that out, I edited it to show what I really have in urls.py.  It is as you point out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need to decode the URL before you pass it along. You can do this with `urllib.unquote`.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote("""http%3A%2F%2F""")
'http://'
```